# How to update a row in Android database

Tags: android, database

Hi all I want to update a row on clicking on update button,but its doesn't work.
I have used following code.

```
 public void btnUpdate(View v) { 
handeler.updateData(updateName.getText().toString(), updatePhone .getText().toString(), updateEmail.getText().toString(),id);
 } 

public void updateData(String name, String phone, String email, String id) {
 ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); 
values.put(COLUMN_FIRST, name); 
values.put(COLUMN_SECOND, phone); values.put(COLUMN_THIRD, email); database.update(TABLE_NAME, values, id, null); 
} 
public void search() {
        Cursor cursor = handeler.getData();
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            String phoneNo;
            phoneNo = updateByPhone.getText().toString();
            do {
                String s1 = cursor.getString(2);
                if (phoneNo.compareTo(s1) == 0) {
                    id = cursor.getString(0);
                    updateName.setText(cursor.getString(1));
                    updateEmail.setText(cursor.getString(3));
                    updatePhone.setText(cursor.getString(2));

                }
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());

        }

    }
```

So if any know please suggest me how to solve it.
Thanks

Comment: how to post code please help me i'm new for stackoverflow

Comment: if you can't do it. just paste it to the edit box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a couple possible issues:

1) You have an extra space `updatePhone .getText().toString()` should be `updatePhone.getText().toString()`

2) you are passing a variable `id` from `btnUpdate` to `updateData` but it is not clear where it is coming from (or even if it actually exists)

My bet is that #2 is your issue.  You probably need to pass the id (I assume that's meant to be the RowId you want to modify in the db) in to the `btnUpdate` method:

```
public void btnUpdate(View v, long id)
```

There are other possibilities... you haven't shown your DB structure, so it could be that some constraint is causing the update to fail.

**EDIT**

The `update method` docs show this:

```
public int update (String table, ContentValues values, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)
```

Note the part `String whereClause`.  That's supposed to be a SQL WHERE statement (without the WHERE).  You are only passing in the id, not a WHERE clause.  Change your call to update to make that a WHERE clause and it should work.  A couple of examples:

```
database.update(TABLE_NAME, values, "_id = " + id, null); 

database.update(TABLE_NAME, values, "_id = '" + id + "'", null);
```

Both examples assume your row id column is labeled _id.

The first example is if `id` is an integer value.  The issue there is that you are setting `id` as a string, so I'm unsure if this is the case or not.  If it is supposed to be an int, you should get it using `id = cursor.getInt(0);` instead of `id = cursor.getString(0);`.

If it truly is a string and not an int, use the second version, which encloses `id` in single quotes to indicate it is a string.

Hope this helps!

Comment: See Barak, there are four columns in my DB ,Searching is done by PhoneNo and if user understand, any modification should be done then just modify this and clicking on update button updated row should be stored .Thats all my requirement.

Comment: I understand that.. you have to pass the row id to the update method, otherwise it doesn't know what to update.

Comment: Where are you calling btnUpdate from?  onListItemClick?  Somewhere else?

Comment: What is the value of `id`?  You put it in the parameters of your call to `updateData`, but I don't see where it's coming from, and I think that may be where the issue lies.

Comment: Id is the Id of searched row.I have mention in code have a look

Answer (score 0):

change the code

```
database.update(TABLE_NAME, values, "_id='?'", new String[]{id});
```

**Edit**

```
database.update(TABLE_NAME, values, "_id=?", new String[]{id});
```

Comment: By wrapping the `?` in quotes `"_id='?'"`, you are search for an _actual_ question mark. If you want the insertion flag simply use `"_id=?"`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got solution ,It was minor mistake,Using following code we can perform update operation

```
database.update(TABLE_NAME, values, BaseColumns._ID + "=" + id, null);
```